# Created torrent goes automatically to Errored and it doesn't work

Tags: windows, bittorrent, qbittorrent

I want to share some files between two computers in different locations, but because they are big I choose to try to use torrent, more precisely **qBittorrent**.

To do that, I opened it, went to **Tools / Torrent Creator** and selected the file (I archived all of them). **Pieces size** I left on *Auto*, **Private torrent** was left *unchecked* and **Start seeding immediately / Ignore share ratio limits for this torrent / Optimize alignment** were *checked*. As for **Fields** I found [this GitHub](https://github.com/ngosang/trackerslist) where there is a list of trackers, and from there I used *trackers_best (20 trackers)* those 20 for **Tracker URLs:.**

But after I'm creating the torrent, it automatically goes to **Errored** status and it doesn't work. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Are the computers on the same *local area network (LAN)*? If they are on two *different* networks, e.g., your home and some else's home, the Torrent server must have a permanent (static) IP address, visible *outside* the LAN. See https://whatismyipaddress.com/how-to-get-static-ip-address

Comment: They are in two different locations, and yes, I have dynamic IP, but should it not work until a new IP is given? My IP changes only after a few days or if I restart my router. But the main problem is that after the torrent is created it doesn't go into "seeding" mode, but in "error".

Comment: Is your *home* IP visible **to those outside it**? See the reference cited about getting a static IP from your ISP.

Comment: Yes it is, and the port is forwarded in router settings. Also my ISP only gives static IP for their business plans, which are a bit over twice as expensive as normal ones, and anyone can apply for them.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that with the version that I have of **qBittorrent** *4.6.3*, it doesn't work if you choose **Start seeding immediately**. I removed the torrent, and added the file it was created manually, and with that it is working. I haven't tried this until now, as I was expecting auto to work and didn't seen any reason to try it manually.

I don't know if this is a problem with the program that I have, or with the version, but that was the solution for me.